# SSL validation error while calling a REST API with self signed certificate from spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, amazon-eks, self-signed-certificate

I created an API in springboot which internally calls a REST API which is self signed

The error i am getting is

```
pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested target
```

**Solution i tried**

Since i am using EKS for deploying my application. what i did is

1. Create a config map with the self signed certificate for the REST API
2. Added The Root CA as a Volume mount in deployment file.
3. Verified whether the CA cert is added to Java trust store i can see the certificate

But when i am still getting the PKIX certification issue.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/14704799) helps.